# How to create a content type based on users with entities?

Tags: users, entities, google-maps

I want to create a content type that I can add to a map view based on nodes. I am using the [GMap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) and [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) modules. There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to add users to view based on nodes. So, I want to make a content type, which is a subset of the users and the fields in my user profiles. I know that I can separately have a map view based on my users, but I need to show them all together users, and 3 spatial content types.

My initial thought was just to copy the raw user data from the database and create a content type and populate it from feeds, but this would lead to a lot of duplicate data in the database.

I've created a content type with an entity reference to users. This lets me manually add content with the user name but I don't know how to share fields between the content types and I don't know how to autopopulate the content from the existing user fields.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing is that u want to populate user fields with content from node, what you can do is enable module, hook_post_action, and after that use its hook "hook_node_update", and you will get user id (uid) from the user reference fields, u can load a user from that uid, using user_load, after that set required value of field, and use user_save function to save that user, If u are using profile2 for the user, then u can use profile2_load_by_user, profile2_save.

Comment: I actually want to load user fields into the node referencing the users.